# GGplot generates two legends with a bubble plot, how to delete one of them

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code block generates a plot with two legends:

```
Spend7d_bubble <- ggplot(cluster_visuals, 
                          aes(x = ltv_7d, y = avg_daily_sessions, 
                              color = factor(cluster8), size = n)) +
                   geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
                   scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 25))
```

[image]

Notice how this generates two legends on the right, one for `n` and one for factor(cluster8).

How can I only include the legend for factor(cluster8) and also rename it to just 'cluster'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
Spend7d_bubble <- ggplot(cluster_visuals, 
                          aes(x = ltv_7d, y = avg_daily_sessions, 
                              color = factor(cluster8), size = n)) +
                   geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
                   scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 25), guide = 'none') +
                   labs(color = "Cluster")
```

Answer (score 1):

Whichever of those aesthetics (`color` or `size`) that you don't want a legend for, should be out of `aes()`. As you see, you don't have any legend for `alpha` in `geom_point` since it is not an argument of `aes`.

```r
ggplot(cluster_visuals, 
        aes(x = ltv_7d, y = avg_daily_sessions, color = factor(cluster8)), size = n) +
 geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
 scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 25))
```